# Python, Word - Fix document.xml errors using Python

Tags: python, xml, ms-word

I am attempting to automate a ongoing issue with xml parsing issues

Unfortunately the app that our company uses has a bug where its not parsing correctly. So when a user uses the & symbol it doesn't get parsed correctly and when the word document is created they are unable to open due to this & symbol. There is currently no plans to fix this :(

Due to this not being fixed the work around is to open the doc in archive (7zip) edit the document.xml and replacing the & with &amp;

I would like to perform this using python instead of having the manual process

1. Open archive (.docx)
2. edit document.xml and replace all & with &amp;
3. Re save archive (.docx)

Any assistance or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated

I've found a lot of references on how to create xml files or read xml files but its not really specific enough for my example.

I've had a look at this one but as there is an xml parsing error currently it fails to read the xml in the first place
[Find and replace XML content in MS Word Document.xml with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053255/find-and-replace-xml-content-in-ms-word-document-xml-with-python)

Comment: why not use jinja2 to gennerator new docx

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.